# SQL Server tempdb permanent tables use cases

Tags: sql-server, tempdb, temp-tables

Are there any use cases for **permanent tables in tempdb** database ? By permanent I mean not using # or ## but creating a real table in tempdb. I know that restarting the sql service will wipe the tempdb, but would this practice be bad for any other reason?

I'm asking because I have one use case for this, I need a temp table but that will be open for more that a sql connection span.

EDIT: the actual data in the long-living temp table are serialized files, not data based on collation or anything else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not create a schema named 'temp' (or Staging) in your database, and create your long lived temp tables in that schema. e.g.

```
create schema [temp] 
     authorization [dbo]

create table [temp].[MyTempTable]
(
   Id int,
   [name] varchar(50),
   ... SomeColumns ...
)
```

**Update**: in response to your extra information, can you use [FILESTREAM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx)? (SQL Server 2008 onwards)

Comment: because the data in the temp table will be used for file transfers from server through network (serialize, then read bytes with sql select), and by files I actually mean the database backups.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is not good for many reasons, for example - if collations of your DB and tempdb (server) does not match - the implicit string comparisons may fail

Answer (score 1):

why does it have to be exactly on the tempdb? 
why not, besides all the other alternatives posted, create a shared DB to hold this table?

Comment: Because tempdb already exists beside the main db for all the customers, creating another database just for this seems like a lot of overhead

Comment: And that overhead becomes even bigger when scaling out to multiple SQL Server instances.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason I'd suggest a different approach is because tempdb is already a bottleneck because of the number of uses that SQL Server puts to it. I wouldn't suggest finding yet another reason to plug stuff into tempdb.

Other than that, tempdb is as good as any other location with the added benefit that after a service restart anything you left in there will be cleaned out.